# Tornado Framework Rendering Blank Page

Tags: python, web, tornado

So i've decided to mess around with Tornado (http://www.tornadoweb.org/), and I've gotten pretty far, however for some reason whenever I call the .generate() function on a view a blank page is generated in the browser (self.write() works however)

My ReqHandler:

```
class Index(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        loader = template.Loader(funcs.static_prefix("/templates/"))
        #self.write("Hello, world") #This works!
        loader.load("test.html").generate(this="hello") #This doesn't :(
```

My template(test.html):

```
<html>

{{ this }}

</html>
```

My logs:

```
13:43:18 web.1     | started with pid 21876
13:43:20 web.1     | WARNING:root:404 GET /favicon.ico (::1) 0.48ms
```

As you can see, if there is an error it is failing silently

Can anybody help?

Comment: As a side question, does anybody know how to pass a dictionary into the template namespace through .generate() ?

Comment: Wow. Forgot to add in the self.write before the .generate line. Embarrassing.

Answer (score 1):

`generate` doesn't write the rendered template to output. simply write it like this:

```
self.render("test.html", this="hello")
```

and make sure to set the template path in your app's config options.